# I want to remove an item in one list and add the same in another List

Tags: android

My requirement is that i want to remove an item in one ListView and add the same in another ListView.

Comment: Add the same model object, which you have removed from the first list to the second list data source

Comment: before you remove it, add this item in the other list, then remove it ! what's the problem in this ?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I just tried:

I made an extra list, else you would get a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

        firstList.add("One");
        firstList.add("Two");
        firstList.add("Three");

        tempList.addAll(firstList);

        // Loop trough list to check items to remove.
        for (String s : tempList) {
            if (s.equals("Two")) {
                firstList.remove(s);
                secondList.add(s);
            }
        }

        // Clear it
        tempList.clear();

        // Print results
        for(String s: firstList) {
            System.out.println("First list:" + s);
        }

        for(String s: secondList) {
            System.out.println("Second list:" + s);
        }
    }
}
```

After this, update your lists in the listViewAdapters!